# How to enable PM_DEBUG?

Tags: 13.04, power-management, debug

I have read that one should set `PM_DEBUG=true` in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions` to get more debugging details in `/var/log/pm-powersave.log`

At least in Ubuntu 13.04, `/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions` contains:

```
[ "${PM_DEBUG}" = "true" ] && {
  export PM_DEBUG
  set -x
}
```

I'm not wearing my programmer hat today. Is is set to true or not?

Answer (score 1):

Trial and error shows that the answer to my question is no, that code does not enable PM_DEBUG.

I put PM_DEBUG=true on a line on its own in the file, and the log shows a lot more detail.